# Removing a periodic noise signal from an output signal in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing

I currently have two periodic signals: an output signal shown in blue and a noise signal shown in green. Both of the curves shown have been shifted to arbitrary values, to clearly separate the curves. Given that both the noise and the output share a similar phase, what I would like to do is to scale the noise signal so it is has the same amplitude as the output signal, then remove the noise from the output signal to remove any oscillations to (hopefully) obtain a straight line running through the mean value of the output signal.

Given that the noise signal is also oscillatory around a mean value, I feel that a simple subtraction of the two signals would not work as this would simply make the oscillation greater.

Both the output signal and noise signal are composed of a different number of data points (output - 58050 data points, noise - 52774 data points)  How can this be achieved in python?

DATA FILES GIVEN BELOW:

Noise: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RZwknUUAXGG31J9u_37aH7m9Fdyy_opE/view?usp=sharing

Output: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E6vLa8Z63UtftrscKmicpid5uBVqoMpv/view?usp=sharing

[image]

The code I have used to import both signals from .csv files and plot them is given below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datathick = "20210726_rig_thick.csv" 
qcmfilter = "20210726_cool_QCM_act.csv"


with open(datathick) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        dates = [str(line.split(',')[0]) for line in lines]
        thick = [float(line.split(',')[1]) for line in lines] #output y data
        z = [float(line.split(',')[2]) for line in lines]

        date_thick = [datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').time() for x in dates]
        
with open(qcmfilter) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        dates_qcm = [str(line.split(',')[0]) for line in lines]
        temp_qcm = [float(line.split(',')[1])+420 for line in lines] #noise y data
        z = [float(line.split(',')[2]) for line in lines]
        
        date_temp_qcm = [datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').time() for x in dates_qcm]

time_list_thick = []
for i in np.arange(0, len(date_thick)):
    q = date_thick[i]
    t = timedelta(hours= q.hour, minutes=q.minute,seconds=q.second, microseconds = q.microsecond).total_seconds()
    time_list_thick.append(float(t))
    
time_list_temp_qcm = []
for i in np.arange(0, len(date_temp_qcm)):
    q3 = date_temp_qcm[i]
    t3 = timedelta(hours= q3.hour, minutes=q3.minute,seconds=q3.second, microseconds = q3.microsecond).total_seconds()
    time_list_temp_qcm.append(float(t3))
#------------------------------------------------
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(7.,7.))

ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_zorder(1)
ax.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude (a.u)')
ax.minorticks_on() # enable minor ticks
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('black')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('black')
ax.set_ylim(440,460)
ax.set_xlim(0, 10000)
ax.tick_params(direction='out', axis='y', which='both', pad=4, colors='black')
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#eeeeee', linestyle='-', zorder=1, linewidth=0.4) # turn on major grid
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#eeeeee', linestyle='-', zorder=1, linewidth=0.4) # turn on minor grid

ax.plot(time_list_thick, thick,color='blue')
ax.plot(time_list_temp_qcm, temp_qcm, color = 'green')

    
    
plt.savefig('QCM.pdf', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', format='pdf')
plt.savefig('QCM.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', format='png')
```

EDIT: After following the suggestions given in the answer from Mozway, I have altered my two data sets to be pandas Series:

```
signal = pd.Series(thick, index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(time_list_thick,unit = 's'))
noise = pd.Series(temp_qcm, index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(time_list_temp_qcm,unit = 's'))
resampled_signal = signal.resample('1S').mean()
resampled_noise  = noise.resample('1S').mean()

true_signal = []
for i in np.arange(0,len(resampled_signal)):
    value = resampled_signal[i]-resampled_noise[i]
    true_signal.append(value)
```

However, the true signal appears choppy with gaps in the data as shown below, nor is the true signal around the mean of the oscillating original signal like I expected originally.
[image]
I will try and find a way to give access to the original data files in order to make things easier for answers.

Comment: You can subtract the noise from the data:
`pure_data = [d - n for d, n in zip(time_list_thick, time_list_temp_qcm)]`
Considering `time_list_thick` is data and `time_list_temp_qcm` is noise

Comment: That is just the x data, what I want to filter is the y data ```thick``` (output) and ```temp_QCM``` (noise). However, both of these data sets have different sizes (58050
and 52774 data points respectively)

Comment: @tjsmert44 have you had a chance to test if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68548751/16343464) worked for you? Could you provide the data of both curves?

Comment: @mozway I have edited the question to update what I have done so far

Comment: @mozway I have also included the data files for you to access and try yourself.

Comment: @tjsmert44 sorry I could only look at your data now. I added another solution with a `merge_asof`. Can you have a look and let me know if this matches your use case?

Comment: Can you please provide the full example? Currently I am not quite sure how you have defined ```df``` in the context of the ```merge_asof``` solution since I am getting issues with  ```merge_asof```

Comment: I added the lines I used to load your data. Note that I added arbitrary constants to the second dataset and the filtered signal for plotting purposes (so that it fits in a small graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I don't have your datasets it is difficult to show you with your actual data, but here are examples of how to compute the difference of two time series with different sampling rates.

### resampling

This example is using [`pandas.Series.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable//reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html) to down-sample the data and align the series. Here I chose a sampling rate that is slightly below the original frequency. You have to choose this parameter wisely (or through trial and error).

```
xs1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
signal = pd.Series(np.sin(xs1)+2,
                   index=pd.TimedeltaIndex(xs1, unit='min'),
                  )
xs2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 120)
noise  = pd.Series(np.sin(xs2)+np.random.normal(scale=0.05, size=len(xs)),
                   index=pd.TimedeltaIndex(xs2, unit='min'),
                  )
resampled_signal = signal.resample('0.1min').mean()
resampled_noise  = noise.resample('0.1min').mean()
pd.DataFrame({'signal': resampled_signal,
              'noise': resampled_noise,
              'signal-noise': resampled_signal-resampled_noise,
             }).plot()
```

[image: signal-noise resampling]

It works also if the global range is unequal, then the difference is computed on the common range. For the graph below the only changes in code are `xs1 = np.linspace(0, 8, 100)` and `xs2 = np.linspace(2, 10, 120)`

[image: unequal ranges]

### interpolation

This example uses [`pandas.DataFrame.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) to interpolate the missing point after concatenation of the two Series. There are many parameters available, so check the documentation to find options best suited to your use case. If your Series are of unequal range, be careful of potential artifacts at the edge (see second graph).

```
xs1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
signal = pd.Series(np.sin(xs1)+2,
                   index=pd.TimedeltaIndex(xs1, unit='min'),
                  )
xs2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 120)
noise  = pd.Series(np.sin(xs2)+np.random.normal(scale=0.05, size=len(xs)),
                   index=pd.TimedeltaIndex(xs2, unit='min'),
                  )

df = pd.concat({'signal': signal,
                'noise': noise,
                }, axis=1)

df = df.interpolate()

df['signal-noise'] = df['signal']-df['noise']

df.plot()
```

[image: interpolation]

Below an example of interpolation artifacts on the edge:
[image: interpolation with artifacts]

### merge_asof

Example of a `merge_asof` with the provided dataset:

loading the data:

```
df_thick = pd.read_csv('20210726_rig_thick.csv', header=None, index_col=0, names=['thick', 'z'])
df_thick.index = pd.to_datetime(df_thick.index)
df_qcm = pd.read_csv('20210726_cool_QCM_act.csv', header=None, index_col=0, names=['temp_qcm', 'z_qcm'])
df_qcm.index = pd.to_datetime(df_qcm.index)
df_qcm['temp_qcm']+=420 # arbitrary to be able to view the lines in the same field.
```

merging:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df_thick, df_qcm,
                   left_index=True,
                   right_index=True,
                   direction='forward')
df.index = df.index - df.index[0]
df['thick_corr'] = df['thick']-df['temp_qcm']+442 # added constant to move curve up for plotting
```

```
>>> df.head()
                             thick  z    temp_qcm  z_qcm  thick_corr
0 days 00:00:00         451.372071  0  445.358141      0  448.013930
0 days 00:00:00.999704  451.366733  0  445.350143      0  448.016589
0 days 00:00:02.003954  451.358724  0  445.341953      0  448.016771
0 days 00:00:03.000006  451.356055  0  445.336466      0  448.019589
0 days 00:00:04.003809  451.350716  0  445.331665      0  448.019051
```

plot:

```
ax = df.reset_index().plot(x='index', y='thick')
df.reset_index().plot(x='index', y='temp_qcm', ax=ax, color='r')
df.reset_index().plot(x='index', y='thick_corr', ax=ax, color='g')
ax.set_ylim(440, 460)
```

[image: merge_asof]

Comment: If the sample duration in both data and noise are equal, but the sample rate is different this is the answer. Since the answer is here I'm not adding another solution but you can use `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` too. See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html

Comment: It works also if the duration is unequal. Try to change one of the bounds in `np.linspace` to see by yourself. The difference will be computed for the common range.

Comment: I didn't mean the code wouldn't work. I meant if the duration is not equal that would not be correct to do as such. Imagine you having 1 second of data and 2 seconds of noise and you re-sample them to have same amount of samples and do the calibration. That defiantly would be wrong.

Comment: Well, you are right, interpolation is an alternative. I added a paragraph about it. However, like resampling, it can lead to artifacts. There is not a *right* and *wrong* way to do it, just various use cases. In any case you have to choose wisely how to resample/interpolate. In the example that you describe, assuming the series are aligned, just one has twice the frequency, I would say it's better to down-sample the highest frequency series.